# No module named keyboard after converting py to exe

Tags: python

I am making an application which automatically enters your username and password. Everything works fine but when I try to convert it to .exe using auto-py-to-exe I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVv63.png) error when I launch main.exe. I have added the modules in the hidden-import menu but it doesn't seem to work. I'm pretty new to this so please keep the answers more simple :D Here is the code of the actual program:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, Listener, KeyCode
mouse = Controller()
keyboards = Controller()
f = open("parolochetach.txt", "r")
list_of_lists = []
for line in f:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    list_of_lists.append(line_list)
f.close()
while True: 
    if keyboard.is_pressed('1') or keyboard.is_pressed('2') or keyboard.is_pressed('3') or keyboard.is_pressed('4') or\
       keyboard.is_pressed('5') or keyboard.is_pressed('6') or keyboard.is_pressed('7') or keyboard.is_pressed('8')\
       or keyboard.is_pressed('9'):
        number = int(keyboard.read_key())
        if number-1 <= len(list_of_lists):
            mouse.position = (404, 415)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            mouse.release(Button.left)
            keyboards.type(list_of_lists[number-1][0])
            mouse.position = (404, 465)
            mouse.press(Button.left)
            mouse.release(Button.left)
            keyboards.type(list_of_lists[number-1][1])
            keyboards.press(Key.enter)
            keyboards.release(Key.enter)
```

I also tried to avoid using the keyboard module but I can't make it work. When I do something simple like:

```
def on_press(key):
if key==KeyCode.from_char('1'):
print("yes")
```

it works with no errors but when I add the click and type functions:

```
number = int(key)
    if number - 1 <= len(list_of_lists):
        mouse.position = (404, 415)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        keyboards.type(list_of_lists[number - 1][0])
        mouse.position = (404, 465)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        keyboards.type(list_of_lists[number - 1][1])
        keyboards.press(Key.enter)
        keyboards.release(Key.enter)
```

it stops working and I get multiple errors:

```
Unhandled exception in listener callback
File"myfile", line 211, ni inner return f(self,*args, **kwargs)
File "", line 284, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "", line 17, in on_press
    number = int(key)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'KeyCode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 31, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "", line 259, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "", line 718, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "", line 211, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "", line 284, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "", line 17, in on_press
    number = int(key)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'KeyCode'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer for another question here and it did work in that case.
Try using pyinstaller and if it can't find modules try this:

From Documentation

> Helping PyInstaller Find Modules
>
> Extending the Path If Analysis recognizes that a module is needed, but
> cannot find that module, it is often because the script is
> manipulating sys.path. The easiest thing to do in this case is to use
> the --paths option to list all the other places that the script might
> be searching for imports:
>
> pyi-makespec --paths=/path/to/thisdir
> --paths=/path/to/otherdir myscript.py
>
> These paths will be noted in the spec file in the pathex argument.
> They will be added to the current sys.path during analysis.